# UI issue while using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor for implmenting multithreading .

Basically each thread is assigned a file , which needs to be uploaded to the server.
After each successfull upload , a notification is issued from the server.

The following code , generates the thread & assigns the file to them.

```
Random random = new Random();
              ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(400));

        int waitTime = 100;
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            int time = random.nextInt(1000);
            waitTime += time;
            newFile = new File((String) it.next());
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    processFile(newFile);
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
```

I have created a Java Applet for rendering the UI.
After each notification , I am updating the file status on the Java Applet window where the updateUI() is called from the processFile().

Before using ExecutorService (recommended for handling multithreading on Java v5.0 & above) , I was using a Thread class for creating the threads & wait-notify for the file upload functionality . The UI displaying each file update status gets properly rendered on using the Thread class but on using the ExecutorService , all the files get uploaded(functionality working) but the UI hangs .

After each file is uploaded successfully , the file upload status for each of the files needs to be updated.

Any suggestions/hints welcome.

Answer (score 0):

when wanting to update the UI from a non EDT thread (the event thread that calls the event handlers and such) you need to use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

and you should NEVER sleep on the EDT or block it as that is the one making sure everything is responsive

however it would be better to use a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) as this implements several things specific to using background threads that need to update the gui

with swingWorker your code will be

```
while (it.hasNext()) {

    final File newFile = new File((String) it.next());
    SwingWorker<Void,Void> work = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {

            processFile(newFile);//do **not** call updateUI() in here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done(){//this gets called after processFile is done on the EDT
            updateUI();
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . I wanted to implement multithreading while uploading the files , so the implementation of the executor is important too . The above code doesn't contain any reference for that.

Comment: if you just eliminate all the sleeps and the awaitTermination you should be fine (you should still shutdown the executor to avoid a thread leak) as long as you don't have more than 400 files (then adding a new job will fail)